# Show how counting semaphores can be implemented using only binary semaphores and ordinary machine instructions?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I am studying for a midterm and this was one of the practice questions: Show how counting semaphores (i.e, semaphores that can hold an arbitrary value) can be implemented using only binary semaphores and ordinary machine instructions?

I'm not even sure where so start. I found this online;

```
P(s) { Pb(mutex_s); s = s-1; if(s < 0) {Vb(mutex_s); Pb(delay_s);} Vb(mutex_s); }
V(s) { Pb(mutex_s); s = s+1; if(s <= 0) Vb(delay_s); else Vb(mutex_s); }
```

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what the answer is telling me.  Can anyone explain this answer to me, or show me in pseudo code how to answer?

Answer (score 5):

I built the following intuition on [Prahbat's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220708/7032781) answer:

What we are trying to replicate:

- Counting Semaphore implies at most N threads are allowed to access a resource

We can do this using binary semaphores:

- The counting semaphore locks access to a thread's critical section if there are N processes already in their critical section

  - => We need a binary semaphore *sectionLock* that tells waiting threads if they can access their critical section (*sectionLock = 1*) or they cannot (*sectionLock = 0*)
- We have to keep track of number of threads accessing the resource in their critical section. Let this counter be an integer *count*

  - *count* decremented on thread entering critical section (i.e. one spot less for a thread in this resource) and incremented on thread exiting critical section (i.e. one spot freed up for a thread in this resource)
  - => *count* is a shared resource and should only be accessed by one thread at a time
  - => we need a binary semaphore, *countLock*, for *count*
- If *count <= 0* then we cannot allow anymore threads into critical section and must wait for *sectionLock* to be released by an exiting thread

Thus the following pseudocode suggests itself

```
P_counting( int count )
   P( countLock )        // Acquire lock to count: countLock <- 0
   count--
   if( count <= 0 )      // If no more threads allowed into critical section
      P( sectionLock )   // Resource full => Acquire section lock: sectionLock <- 0
      V( countLock )     // Release lock to count: countLock <- 1
   else
      V( countLock)

V_counting( int count )
   P( countLock )
   count++
   if( count > 0)        // Release sectionLock if resource is freed up
      V(sectionLock)     // countLock released after sectionLock so that waiting
      V(countLock)       // threads do not jump in when before resource is available
   else
      V(countLock)
```

Please let me know if I have got something wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `P(sectionLock)` come after `V(countLock)` in `P_counting`? If a process tries to acquire the section lock before it releases the counting lock and is blocked, the counting lock will remain blocked. Therefore, no process will be allowed to move past the `P(countLock)` line in `V_counting`, thus keeping the critical section locked indefinitely. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
CSem(K) cs { // counting semaphore initialized to K
    int val ← K; // the value of csem
    BSem gate(min(1,val)); // 1 if val > 0; 0 if val = 0
    BSem mutex(1); // protects val

    Pc(cs) {
        P(gate)
        a1: P(mutex);
        val ← val − 1;
        if val > 0
        V(gate);
        V(mutex);
    }

    Vc(cs) {
        P(mutex);
        val ← val + 1;
        if val = 1
        V(gate);
        V(mutex);
    }
}
```

source: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~shankar/412-Notes/10x-countingSemUsingBinarySem.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> Let x, y be binary semaphore. We are going to implement counting semaphore S by it.P stand for wait operation and V for signal.
>   Since we are taking S=4 so only 4 process can enter critical section.

```
S = 4, x = 1, y = 0;

/*---P(S)---*/
{P(x);S--;if(s<=0){V(x);P(y);}else V(x); }

/*--CRITICAL SECTION--*/

/*--V(S) ---*/
  { P(x); S++;IF(S>0){ V(y);V(x); }else V(x);}
```

> NOTE: P(x) decrease value of x by 1 while V(x) increases by 1,same for y. y is called hanging semaphore as P(y) put all those 
>    process in queue if  S< 0.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
int s = N;
semaphore mutex_s = 1;
semaphore delay_s = 0;

p(s) = down
  down(mutex_x);
  s--;

  if (s< n)
    up(mutex_s)
    down(delay_s)
  up(mutex_s)

V(s) = up
  down(mutex_s)
  s++
  if (s<=0)
    up(delay_s)
  up(mutex_s)
```

Comment: Great solution, but i think that line 7 is wrong.
It should be: "if (s < 0)..." **not** "if (s < n)..."

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar question which I think would have the same answer, i.e., "How can you implement a counting semaphore using mutex".

Notice that binary semaphores can be thought of as mutexes. In fact, on systems that do not provide mutex locks, binary semaphores can be used instead for providing mutual exclusion.

```
Mutex counting_mutex;    // used for accessing the shared variable count
Integer count = n;       // number of resource instances
Mutex mutex;             // the counting semaphore as mutex/binary semaphore
List waiting_list = [];  // list of waiting processes

/* ... */

// Entry Section
acquire(counting_mutex);
count--;
release(counting_mutex);

if (count < 0)
    add this process to waiting_list and have it sleep()

acquire(mutex);
/* ... Critical Section ... */
release(mutex);

// Exit Section
acquire(counting_mutex);
count++;
release(counting_mutex);

if (count <= 0)
    pull a process from waiting_list and call wakeup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Associated with each counting semaphore are two binary semaphores, M, used
for mutual exclusion, and B, used for blocking. Also associated with each
counting semaphore is a counter that holds the number of ups minus the number
of downs, and a list of processes blocked on that semaphore. To implement
down, a process first gains exclusive access to the semaphores, counter,
and list by doing a down on M. It then decrements the counter. If it is zero or
more, it just does an up on M and exits. If M is negative, the process is put on
the list of blocked processes. Then an up is done on M and a down is done on
B to block the process. To implement up, first M is downed to get mutual
exclusion, and then the counter is incremented. If it is more than zero, no one
was blocked, so all that needs to be done is to up M. If, however, the counter
is now neg ative or zero, some process must be removed from the list. Finally,
an up is done on B and M in that order.

Both question and answer is from the book Operating Systems of Andrew S. Tanenbaum